# Terraform media services using Version 2 instead of version 3

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have researching the documentation and I see that terraform support deployment for [media services](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/media_services_account) and I like to know how can I use Version 2 instead of default version 2 Deployment:

Can you suggest how can I use specific version when deploying using Terraform?

I try manual creating two media services and to find the API using but not luck since I can't find anything regarding that:

Here is the example if the exported template > this is regarding version 2 and the version 3 is the same

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "mediaservices_testversion2_name": {
            "defaultValue": "testversion2",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "storageAccounts_sinclairdevamsstracc_externalid": {
            "defaultValue": "//////////////////",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Media/mediaservices",
            "apiVersion": "2015-10-01",
            "name": "[parameters('/////////////')]",
            "location": "West US 2",
            "properties": {
                "storageAccounts": [
                    {
                        "id": "[parameters('storageAccounts_//////////_externalid')]",
                        "isPrimary": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The code that I use is very simple:

```
#Azure Provider Configuration
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.82.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  tenant_id = var.tenant_id
  client_id = var.client_id
  features {}
  }

locals {
      StreamingEndpoints = 1
}


#Storage Account Resource
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "stracc" {
  name                = "${lower(var.customer)}${lower(var.env)}${lower(var.product)}stracc"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  location                 = var.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"


}

#Resource Group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = upper("${var.customer}-${var.product}-RG-${var.env}-TEST")
  location = var.location


}

resource "azurerm_media_services_account" "media" {
  name                = "${lower(var.customer)}${lower(var.env)}${lower(var.product)}-media"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  storage_account {
    id         = azurerm_storage_account.stracc.id
    is_primary = true
  }

}
resource "azurerm_media_streaming_endpoint" "example" {
  count = local.StreamingEndpoints
  name                        = "${lower(var.customer)}${lower(var.env)}${lower(var.product)}-CH0${count.index + 1}"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                    = var.location
  media_services_account_name = azurerm_media_services_account.media.name
  scale_units                 = 1
  access_control {
    ip_allow {
      name    = "AllowedIP"
      address = "192.168.1.1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Igor, I don't think its possible to create a V2 media services API using various IaC tools.It by default creates V3 media services API. let me check again and get back with confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this using `Terraform` and `ARM template` as well but there is no parameters to `Enable the Classic API's` option like it can be seen from Portal.

[image]

It has been limited to be deployed from Portal itself , as [Media Service API v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/release-notes#azure-media-services-v2-api-and-sdks-deprecation-announcement) has been deprecated.

So, if you want to want to use [Media Service V2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-portal-create-account) until its fully deprecated i.e.`29 February 2024` then as a solution please deploy it from portal.

Comment: Thank you for testing and confirming @AnsumanBal-MT

Comment: Np!! Glad to be of Help @Igor..